# How to install PyGI (Python Gobject Introspection) on Windows?

Tags: python, windows-installer, pygtk, pygobject

Installing the python interpreter:
http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/python-2.7.2.msi
and:
http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.24/pygtk-all-in-one-2.24.0.win32-py2.7.msi
run:
python
import gtk
...works

Is there a PyGI all in one installer?
run:
python
import gi
Error: Unable to import module gi
...how to make it work on Windows? On Ubuntu 11.04 runs without installing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you run into two problems here. First of all, I'm not sure that the PyGObject versions featuring introspection are available for Windows. More importantly, only the GTK 2 libraries are available for Windows, but unfortunately support for introspection with GTK 2 is incomplete.

Comment: This might be inaccurate but I'm having trouble loading http://live.gnome.org/PyGObject to confirm it.

Comment: Thank you Brandon for clarifications.
PyGObject 2.28 works with GTK+ 2 on Linux, and I thought someone has managed to compile an all in in one installer for Windows. Looks like we have to wait for GTK+ 3 for Windows.

Comment: Hi all, can't find anything on the web. Has the status of the issue chan ged ? Can we use gi.repository in windows now ?

Answer (score 2):

2016 :
There is now an all in one installer :

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/?source=navbar

I have installed Python 3.4.3, then pygi-aio-3.18.2_rev10.
Works fine in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I have do some work to port the gobject introspection system to windows:
https://github.com/tomnotcat/glib-win32

Comment: Hey, can you tell me how I can use it? I think, it'd be best if you updated the README file with the instructions. Thanks.