# PyGObject in Python 3 on windows

Tags: python, windows, installation, python-3.x, pygobject

Does anyone know if its possible to install PyGObject/Gtk+3 on windows for Python 3?  I have found installers on gnome's website for Python 2 ([here](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygobject/)), and several statements that it works with Python 3 (e.g. [here](http://readthedocs.org/docs/python-gtk-3-tutorial/en/latest/install.html)), but no installer.  The compilation instructions all seem to use jhbuild, which from what I can make out is a linux tool.  Do I need to compile PyGObject to get it working, and if so, how?  Or is there an easier way?  What would be great is a guide or howto, but such a ting doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: [This might be of interest.](http://www.mail-archive.com/pygtk@daa.com.au/msg20856.html) I'm not sure if anything has changed significantly in the past few months (probably not).

Comment: Check this https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Answer (score 5):

Since this is the most rated question in the topic, I'd like to update the answer. Here is available installer for windows 32bit:

It contain complete SDK-like package. And complete libraries collection too. http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/pygi-aio-3.10.2-win32_rev10-setup.exe/download

Comment: https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/PyGObject This seems to be linked as the homepage and seems to link back to the project for download.

Answer (score 2):

I searched for the same thing not so long ago. I couldn't really find much information but [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275322/how-to-install-pygi-python-gobject-introspection-on-windows/7283395#comment15677015_7283395.)

I ended up giving up on GTK+ and switch to xwpython which is really os independant

Answer (score 1):

did you try the offical pypi page https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

I was able to install GTK